# Move bootstrap col to bottom without position absolute

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have three blocks like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left-top"></div>              
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 right-top">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left-bottom"></div>              
    <div class="col-xs-6 right-bottom">
```

But on a smaller screen size I want actually this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left-top -> Top"></div>              
<div class="col-xs-6 right-top -> Middle">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left-bottom -> Bottom"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 right-bottom -> Middle">
```

So the 4 blocks are placed under each other but in a different order, but I don't want to use position absolute for this.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap 3's **pull** and **push** classes to fiddle your way through this. Full explanation can be found [over here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering).

But for your code you could do the following:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 left-top"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 right-top"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-push-6 right-bottom"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-pull-6 left-bottom></div>
```

This will cause the divs to change places once it hits the sm-point. The baseline rule here is to order the divs in your HTML like you want them to be in the very last view, which in this case is mobile view, and mess around with `col-sm-push` and `col-sm-pull` in order to get them in a different place when you're still on desktop view.